# Wikitude API for iPad 2

Tags: objective-c, ipad, augmented-reality, wikitude

with the introduction of iPad 2, I would like to use the Wikitude API in my present app which is available for iPhone, unfortunately I cant figure out how to make that my POIs appear in the whole screen, and not just in a section which is the size of an iPhone screen.

I have tried to modify the xibs, but it doesnt work.

Do you have any idea of how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately the Wikitude API currently does not support the iPad2 - it is iPhone only at the moment.

Best regards,
Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

The Wikitude SDK does support iPads since 2012 - find the iOS version here:
http://www.wikitude.com/products/wikitude-sdk